# Convert an array of array of objects to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash, javascript-objects

**Current Invalid Input**

> ```
> boxlist = [
>  {
>    boxId:'94sdsd65cc9'
>    boxSize:'Small'
>    boxType:'box'
>    items:(2) [Array(12), Array(2)]
>  }
> ]
> ```

Expanded above Items ***array of array*** sample:

> ```
> items : [
>   [{id: 1, name: "item1", write: true}],
>   [{id: 3, name: "item3", write: true}]
> ]
> ```

**Expected Output**

> ```
> boxlist = [
>  {
>    boxId:'94sdsd65cc9'
>    boxSize:'Small'
>    boxType:'box'
>    items:(2) [{.12.}, {.2.}]
>  }
> ]
> ```

Required Items ***array of objects*** sample:

> ```
> items = [
>   {id: 1, name: "item1", write: true},
>   {id: 3, name: "item3", write: true}
> ]
> ```

Tried to use

1. items.flat() , but didn't work, it had no impact on my array of array
2. flatten, flattenDeep, flattenDepth for loadash but didn't work

Comment: in your example of `current input`, on one hand u have `items[0]` being `Array(12)` but in your *"expanded form"*, you have `items[0]` as `Array(1)`, can you please clear that up for me? which one is it really?

Comment: "*Tried to use [...] items.flat() , but didn't work, it had no impact on my array of array*" [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/qamirajozu/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: `[ [{a:1}] , [{b:2}] ].flat()` does turn to `[{a:1}, {b:2}]` so could you please show a clearer picture of what's actually going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
boxlist.map((list) => {
    list.items = list.items.flat() // flattens the array of array
    return list
})
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain the structure of [ {12 objects}, {2 objects} ]  rather returns [ {14 objects} ]